# Laravel validation gte rule

Tags: validation, laravel-validation, laravel-5.8

I am working on a web app and I needed to validate a form. The form has two numeric fields and I need to make sure one is greater than or equal to the other.

So I used these rules.

```
[
     'adults' => ['required', 'numeric'],
     'people' => ['required', 'numeric', 'gte:adults'],
]
```

Everything else is working except in one case. Say `adults` is missing or `null` but `people` is not. Then I would expect `adults is required` message. But instead I get

```
InvalidArgumentException: The values under comparison must be of the same type.
```

So it seems `gte` rules is comparing types of the two fields even when one is `null` with a `required` rule. How can I get around this?

Comment: What are the validation errors and what is the request body looking like?

Comment: I updated my question to include the error I am getting in a particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a problem with the order the rules are evaluated.

If `adults` is evaluated first, It would fail with `adults is required` error. However, in case `people` is evaluated first, it tries to compare it to adults, throwing the error. You could solve this by conditionally adding the last rule:

```
[
     'adults' => ['required', 'numeric'],
     'people' => ['required', 'numeric', $request->has('adults') ? 'gte:adults' : ''],
]
```